# WL.Logger.(log and warn) not printed out on Logcat

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, logcat, mobilefirst-server

MobileFirst 6.3.0 plugin on Eclipse.

When execute the mobile application on Localhost using android sdk device 'emulator-5554', the messages are printed out on Logcat; but when connect to remote server (WAS server ver. 8.5.5.8) the messages are not printed out.

I tried in another WAS server ver. 8.5.5.8, and the debug messages (WL.Logger.log - WL.Logger.warn) were printed out on LogCat.

Is there any configuration in the WAS server that allows to print out the debug messages..??

I tried changing the log level detail (Troubleshooting > Logs and Trace > server > Change log detail levels) but it didn't work.

> eg:
>
> WL.Logger.warn("Event source callback is already registered with alias: " + alias); WL.Logger.log("doSubscribeSuccess");

Answer (score 0):

Not printed out where?

You have the device connected via cable to a local Eclipse with LogCat opened, but the app connects to a remote server?

Either way these log levels are printed to the messages.log file of the server, local or remote (depending on which server you're attempting to connect to).

Comment: The device is an AVD, started from local Eclipse and Logcat vie opened. The App connects to a remote server.

Comment: The device is an AVD started from local Eclipse and Logcat view opened. The App connects to a remote server.
I also check the message.log file (SystemOut.log) in the remote server, but the log messages are not logged there.
When run the App pointing to localhost, the log messages are printed out in the Logcat view, but they aren't printed out when pointing to remote server.